# annotations in annotated_heatmap plotly lost when adding a subplot

Tags: data-science, data-visualization, heatmap, interactive, plotly-python

I'm trying to subplot annotated_heatmap instance with go table , when Im subploting both the annotations on the heatmap are gone and I can't reproduce it .

```
[I want my heatmap will be as this on ][1]

[but this is what I get][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8aEc.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP9cp.png

here is my code-
```

#here I create the subplots

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=1,
    shared_xaxes=False,
    vertical_spacing=0.05,
    specs=[[{"type": "table"}],
           [{"type": "scatter"}]],
    subplot_titles=("AA table","AA heatmap")
)
#here i add go table 
fig.add_trace(fig1.data[0],
    row=1, col=1)
#here i add the heatmap
fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0],row=2,col=1)            
             


fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Wild Type amino acid", row=2, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="New amino acid", row=2, col=1)



fig.update_layout(
    height=800,
    showlegend=False,
    title_text="Amino acids changes",
)




fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided sample data or how **fig1** and **fig2** are created.  So have used https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap/
- as stated `annotated_heatmap()` is deprecated and it's now recommended to use `px.imshow()`
- using this approach it works (have not focused on table rows/cols being correct)

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

z = [
    [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
    [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2],
    [0.2, 0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
    [0.9, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0],
    [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 1],
]

fig1 = go.Figure(go.Table(cells={"values": z}))
# annotated heatmap
fig2 = px.imshow(z, text_auto=True)

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=1,
    shared_xaxes=False,
    vertical_spacing=0.05,
    specs=[[{"type": "table"}], [{"type": "scatter"}]],
    subplot_titles=("AA table", "AA heatmap"),
)
# here i add go table
fig.add_trace(fig1.data[0], row=1, col=1)
# here i add the heatmap
fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0], row=2, col=1)

fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Wild Type amino acid", row=2, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="New amino acid", row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(
    height=800,
    showlegend=False,
    title_text="Amino acids changes",
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Rob , thanks for your answer! the problem is that I want the heatmap hover labale would be diffrent from the annotation of the heatmap and I cant do it  px.imshow().

Comment: this is how it done with annotated heatmap-fig2 = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z_axis,annotation_text=annot_tx ,text=position_within, x=WT_AA, y=new_AA, font_colors=['green'], hoverinfo='text',showscale=True, colorscale='YlOrBr')

Comment: I would recommend moving to `imshow()` and text capabilities new in 5.5.  `ff.create_annotated_heatmap()` uses layout annotations rather than capabilities in the trace which will make it more difficult to handle.  hence reason it is deprecated